# While setting property value conditionally on a Spring bean, SpEL conditional operator not evaluating as expected (using XML config)

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-el

In Spring batch, I need to inject a property conditionally on a bean based on a flag being passed from Job Parameter. 

e.g. If Job parameter 'ISCAR' is "true", I need to pass the string "Car.xsd" as the property otherwise, "Bus.xsd".

Where am I doing wrong?

This is what I have tried -

Try#1

```
   <property name="schemaFileName" value="#{ jobParameters['ISCAR'] == 'true' ? 'Car.xsd : Bus.xsd'}" />
```

Gives :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to placeholder: 
>   jobParameters['ISCAR'] == 'true' ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'

Try#2

```
<property name="schemaFileName" value="#{ #{jobParameters['ISCAR'] == 'true'} ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'}" />
```

Gives :

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to
>   placeholder:  true ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'

Try#3

```
<property name="schemaFileName" value="${ #{jobParameters['ISCAR'] == 'true'} ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'}" />
```

Gives :

> Evaluates to 'Bus.xsd' with single quotes, even though the condition
>   is true and Car.xsd was expected

Here is the XML config of bean used as tasklet -

```
 <batch:step id="validateXMLSchema" abstract="true">
         <batch:tasklet ref="xmlSchemaValidator" />
    </batch:step>
```

Here is the Java snippet of setting Job parameters

```
JobParametersBuilder paramBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
paramBuilder.addString("ISCAR", "true");
```

Edit : Adding Stack Trace

> JobExecution: id=159480, startTime=Thu Jul 25 14:10:24 EDT 2019,
>   endTime=Thu Jul 25 14:10:25 EDT 2019, lastUpdated=Thu Jul 25 14:10:25
>   EDT 2019, status=FAILED,
>   exitStatus=exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lazyBindingProxy.xmlSchemaValidator#sysinit' defined in class path
>   resource [xxx-job-detail-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to
>   placeholder:  jobParameters.getString('ISCAR')=='true' ? 'Car.xsd' :
>   'Bus.xsd'     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.util.PlaceholderTargetSource.getTarget(PlaceholderTargetSource.java:183)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:182)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.beforeStep(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:348)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchJob(StepRunner.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.test.StepRunner.launchStep(StepRunner.java:156)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.test.AbstractJobTests.launchStep(AbstractJobTests.java:218)
>     at
>   org.springframework.batch.test.AbstractJobTests.launchStep(AbstractJobTests.java:200)
>     at
>   mypackage.test.TestXXXJob.testXMLValidationStep(TestXXXJob.java:43)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to
>   placeholder:  jobParameters.getString('ISCAR')=='true' ? 'Car.xsd' :
>   'Bus.xsd'     at
>   org.springframework.batch.core.scope.util.PlaceholderTargetSource$1.convertIfNecessary(PlaceholderTargetSource.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1365)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     ... 50 more , job=[JobInstance: id=42213,
>   JobParameters=[{REQUESTFILEPATH=src/test/resources/testxml,
>   REQUESTFILENAME=car_sample.xml, ISCAR=true,
>   runCounter=0.029477961569429834}], Job=[TestJob]]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are referencing `jobParameters` as if it were a map, I get

> EL1027E: Indexing into type 'org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters' is not supported

with that.

This...

```
"#{jobParameters.getString('ISCAR') == 'true' ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'}"
```

...works fine for me.

**EDIT**

Here's my test class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So57204900Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So57204900Application.class, args);
    }

    @Value("#{jobParameters.getString('ISCAR') == 'true' ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'}")
    private String param;


    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println(param);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public JobParameters jobParameters() {
        return new JobParametersBuilder().addString("ISCAR", "false").toJobParameters();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work for me. I am still getting  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to placeholder:  jobParameters.getString('ISCAR') == 'true' ? 'Car.xsd' : 'Bus.xsd'

Comment: I edited the answer with my test class; can you edit your question and show the complete stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the question with complete stacktrace @user:1240763

Comment: It looks like you are using a very, very, old version of Batch; that class (`PlaceholderTargetSource`) hasn't existed since 2.2 which was released in 2013. 2.1 and earlier uses `spring-framework` version 2.5.6 which doesn't support SpEL at all. SpEL was introduced in Spring 3.0. The reason you are getting an obscure message is that `#{...}` is not a recognized place holder. The current batch version is 4.1.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gary. We're using Spring Batch 2.1.0.M1 with Spring 3.1 with XML-based configuration in the application.  Unfortunately, the choice of version is not something I have a control over. I have added spring-expression 3.1 dependency in my pom. But that also did not resolve this.     To solve this issue, I will now handle this logic within the bean in [at]BeforeStep.

Comment: `2.1.0.M1` That was an early pre-release milestone of 2.1; you should NOT be using such milestones in production. The latest 2.1.x version is 2.1.9 from mid-2012.